# What world did Odin offer Sandman?

Tags: dc, the-sandman

In Neil Gaiman's Sandman, in chapter 5 of "Season of Mists" Odin offers Sandman a world he created in order to learn about Ragnarok. We can see some warriors from this world, whose Odin, to his surprise did not create himself:

[image]

Is there any more info what is this world? Is this one of DC Comics universes?

If so, who are the superheroes visible there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What Odin offers Sandman (AKA Morpheus, AKA Dream) is a simulated world created by Odin who had been searching for a way to thwart the real Ragnarök.  A simulation in which most of the [Justice Society of America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_Society_of_America) had been caught, including the [Hawks](http://th07.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/f/2012/029/0/9/golden_age_hawkman_and_hawkgirl_wallpaper_by_kalel1986-d4o1hx8.png) and [Golden Age Sandman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman_%28Wesley_Dodds%29) who, it is established, has some of Morpheus' or [The Dreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreaming_%28comics%29)'s essence in him.

[image][image][image]

To be specific in 1986 DC Comics decided to *write-off* the JSA from active continuity. The result was the [Justice Society Special: Last Days of the Justice Society](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Days_of_the_Justice_Society_Special_Vol_1_1http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Days_of_the_Justice_Society_Special_Vol_1_1), a one-shot story involving most of the JSA.  In the story, written by [Roy Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Thomas), the team is forced to battle in an ever-repeating Ragnarök-like Limbo.

Only [Power Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Girl), [the Star-Spangled Kid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_Pemberton), [the Spectre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(comics)#Golden_Age_version) and [Doctor Fate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Fate) escaped the cataclysm.

A minor retcon by [Neil Gaiman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Gaiman), along with [Matt Wagner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Wagner), suggested that Golden Age Sandman's (Wesley Dodds) chosen identity was a result of Dream's absence from the realm The Dreaming [events covered in [Preludes and Nocturnes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Preludes_%26_Nocturnes)], and that Dodds carries an aspect of that mystical realm.  This would explain Dodds' prophetic dreams in the DC Vertigo series, [Sandman Mystery Theatre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandman_Mystery_Theatre) by Matt Wagner.

Answer (score 6):

The superheroes visible are (silver age) Hawkman and (golden age) Sandman. They exist (together) within a very wide range of DC worlds and fight together in the "[Justice Society of America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_Society_of_America)" comics.

As @22ndCenturyFza has noted, the world in question was the bottle-universe shown in the [Justice Society Special : Last Days of the Justice Society](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Days_of_the_Justice_Society_Special_Vol_1_1http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Days_of_the_Justice_Society_Special_Vol_1_1).

> Dr. Fate takes the heroes to the world of Asgard, the home of the
>   Nordic gods, also revealing that Hitler has linked the fate of their
>   Ragnarok, the "twilight of the gods", to that of the universe.
>
> Knowing that the only way to keep Hitler's linkage of the Ragnarok to
>   the universe's destruction from taking place is to change the course
>   of the Ragnarok's outcome, Dr. Fate merges the members of the Justice
>   Society along with Sandy and Hawkgirl with the Nordic gods who are out
>   to battle the demons come to destroy them. Team members Flash, Johnny
>   Thunder, Green Lantern, Starman, Hawkman, Hawkgirl, and Wildcat perish
>   in the battle,

[image]